# General topology - challenging problem.

Tags: general-topology, contest-math, low-dimensional-topology

While revising my knowledge in general topology, I tackle various difficult problems. I came across one particular problem at which I got completely stuck. Below is the problem:

**Assume**: on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ there are the set of countably many equilateral triangles $\{ T_{i}\}_{i=1}^{+\infty}$ and the set of countably many straight lines $\{ L_{i}\}_{i=1}^{+\infty}$.

**Prove**: there exists a point that is neither equidistant to any pair of straigth lines from $\{ L_{i}\}_{i=1}^{+\infty}$ nor a vertex of any triangle from $\{ T_{i}\}_{i=1}^{+\infty}$.

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Why did my post obtain 2 negative remarks? I am quite baffled...

Comment: Quite likely because you forgot to include some thoughts of your own on the question. Also, if this is from a contest, you should tell us whether it's still ongoing.

Comment: I usually don't vote down for that, but I also understand why some people do. The question is really nice, and I know the solution. But without any background (where did you see the problem, why is it interesting to you, is it a homework?) and any sign of own efforts, I feel quite unmotivated to write up the solution.

Comment: @Arnaud Mortier this question did not appear in any contest(unless it was covered during USSR). I took this question from old textbook that contains quite interesting question (its cover is however damaged so I can't tell the author of this question).

Comment: @A.Pongracz this question is not any sort of homework (in UK now there is summer vacation). Below I will provide, hopefully, thorough responses to your concerns.

Comment: @A.Pongracz I did a couple of questions from Viro's "Elementary topology textbook" - http://www.pdmi.ras.ru/~olegviro/topoman/eng-book-nopfs.pdf). However, plenty of them in this textbook appeared to me as easy. Hence I decided to look for more challenging problems. At my home my grandfather has a big library with plenty of old textbooks. I asked him whether he has any script with interesting problems from general topology. He gave me one of his script. In this I found this problem.

Comment: I give you a hint.

Comment: $A.Pongracz regarding my thoughts, I considered for a while a proof by contradicition by assuming lack of existence of such points and, intuitively speaking, to find some contradiction arising from the fact that we have countably many triangles and lines in this problem.

Comment: @A.Pongracz I would love to hear a hint from you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given two lines, the points equidistant to them is a pair of perperdicular lines. As there are countably many given lines, the set of all these pairs of perpendicular lines is also a countable collection of lines.

Hint: pick a line that is different from all of these, and see what happens on it.

(Why can you pick such a line? What is the cardinality of the points on this line? What is the cardinality of points that you cannot pick on this line?)

I would say that this problem has nothing to do with topology. It is set theory.

Comment: Set theory and some geometry, but definitely no topology.

Comment: @A.Pongracz I see the solution. Thank you very much for your help!